# EVE Online API vs. CCP SDD?

Tags: eve-online

What is the difference in the data that is available in the EVE Online [CCP Static Data Dump](http://wiki.eve-id.net/CCP_Static_Data_Export) and the [API](http://wiki.eve-id.net/API)? Does the Static Dump contain all the data that could have been queried for the API for that period?

Answer (score 3):

API gives account and character information. Such as skill progress, inventory, etc.

The static data dump gives static data, as explained in that wiki page. This includes map information, details of every possible item in the game, and so on.